# Computer not booting up

Tags: hard-drive, boot, cpu, power-supply, hardware-failure

The hdd light comes up for a few seconds and goes off and the keyboard lights flash for just a millisecond. I tested the power supply with paper clip method and power supply works fine. There's no display on the monitor so can't enter the BIOS. When I remove the RAM there's a 3 long beep sound and yet no display. What can be done? It was working fine till last night.

Comment: What make is your BIOS? Your motherboard?

Comment: Well the mother board is intel D945GCNL and idk the make bios

Comment: Could anyone do me a favor by telling what happens if you don't connect the 4pin power supply connector to the motherboard??

Comment: Probably your CPU will not work! Sometimes, it can damage other components. 4 pin standalone cable is usually used to fuel the CPU.

Comment: Disconnect all components from motherboard (except processor) and check if the SMPS and CPU cooling fans spins. If yes, connect one by one **after disconnecting power each time** 1: RAM modules, 2:Monitor, 3:Keyboard and mouse, 4: HDD/SSD (which contains OS), 5:Optical drive, 6: Other peripheral devices.

Comment: The fans spin but the display doesn't show and hdd doesn't load up fully

Answer (score 0):

Taking everything apart, and putting it back together rearranging things may help. Try removing all unnecessary components, and try trial and error. If you have spare parts, switch some components out. Start with a different PSU.

Comment: Nope didn't work.. Any way to test the RAM